# Flask: passing boolean values in json in request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Using the Python `requests` library, how can I send a boolean value in request body? I've tried:

`request_body = {'someBooleanValue': true}`. => NameError: name 'true' is not defined

`request_body = {'someBooleanValue': True}` => Only unicode objects are escapable. Got True of type <class 'bool'>.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `request_body = json.dumps({'someBooleanValue': True})`

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the dictionary with boolean values as the json parameter in the request method:

```
def request(self, method, url,
            params=None, data=None, headers=None, cookies=None, files=None,
            auth=None, timeout=None, allow_redirects=True, proxies=None,
            hooks=None, stream=None, verify=None, cert=None, json=None):
```

you can do json=request_body here

Also, I dont see what flask has to do with this question - the requests library is a separate python library and not related to flask. Let me know if I misunderstood something here.

Comment: You're right... Flask has nothing to do with the Requests library and I have modified the question.

You're answer isn't what I was looking for.  I'm trying to pass a boolean value as a boolean data type and not as a string.

Comment: if you use the json parameter, a boolean type will not be converted to a string. you can do payload={v = True}, and then request(json=payload) and it will stay boolean